# Standard Package updates of selinux-policy-*

Tags: security, upgrade, selinux

I am wondering if after installing an update of a selinux-policy-* package you are using, do you need to reset all the labels in the system (i.e. fixfiles onboot) in order to keep the policy effective?

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on which distribution you are using, but in Fedora (and therefore in most or all Fedora-derived distributions including Red Hat Enterprise Linux and CentOS) the `selinux-policy-targeted` package includes a postinstall script with `restorecon` and `fixfiles` commands, so it should not be necessary.